# Google Sheets - Have working Tabs retain the entered information

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that multiple people are working on, but only on certain rows in the sheet that they mark with their name. There is a master sheet where they are marking which ones they're working on, then a tab for each named person. The tab with their name gets populated using a "=QUERY(Master!A3:AX,"select * Where L='NAME'")". The goal of the tab is so they can work on their own stuff without having to scroll through the thousands of rows to find their next entry. Getting the info from the master to the tab is working fine, but when they are working on their tab, they add information to a few new columns at the end of the query. This is where my problem lies, when they go and tag another entry on the master as theirs, the columns they added information to already do not move with the entrys, they just get pushed up or down depending on the new entry placement.

Is there something I can do that will still pull in the data from the master sheet to the corresponding tab, but then keep what the staff is actually entering/working on, to remain in line with the entry that got pulled in? The whole process is sort of useless if their work is not retained as they are working through it.

For example, the query pulls in column A-L, then they are adding information to column M and N for the management to read and make decisions off of their input. I need the information they enter into column M and N to remain with the row the query originally pulled in. The master is sorted by a unique number in column A that needs to remain in that order, so they may add new entries randomly as they assign rows to themselves.

Comment: you would need to sort your master/slave sheets with asc/desc sequence

Comment: How would I formulate that if I am able to sort it via asc/desc? I just need all the cells to remain in line when a new cell is added across the board.